# How to run an Apache server with a custom configuration in macOS

Tags: apache-http-server

I am on MacOS 10.15.7 (Catalina) with Apache 2.4.53.

I need to run the Apache HTTP server with alternate configuration files. The usual documentation says that `apachectl -k start -f /path/to/conf/file` is the recommended way to do it and not just to use the demon `httpd` directly. However, after looking inside the script, I notice that `apachectl` is just doing that. So what is its specific value?

Or to ask differently: what specific magic happens, when `apachectl` is called just with simple `start, stop, restart` commands and when `launchctl` is run with a `plist` file?

When I want to edit the `apachectl` script to make my own custom script, what changes would I make? Would I need a custom `plist`, too?

I expected that running with a custom config file would be done in more or less the "same" way as with the standard config.

Comment: Why? Apache is fairly simple and custom configs are not needed.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: Thank you for asking. The scenario of running multiple configurations of Apache, even in parallel on the same machine, is discussed here, for example: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/RunningMultipleApacheInstances

Comment: FollowUp: The question is: how do we "properly" fire them up on MacOS given the recommendation for 'apachectl'.